# Realistic wrapped plastic

Tags: modeling, texturing, transparency, blend-files

How can I make a transparent plastic texture like this?

[image: Both the wrinkles and the transparent texture of the bag]

Answer (score 1):

Create a plane, subdivide it 100, give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Noise* as texture, give it a *Physic > Collision*, create another plane that you subdivide 50 and that you put above:

[image]

Make the first plane invisible, give a *Cloth* physic to the second one, enable its *Object Collisions > Self Collisions*, play the animation until it reach the floor:

[image]

Give a material that is a mix between a *Glossy* and a *Transparent* node, give them a slightly grey color, add a *Noise Texture* thatyou plug into a *Bump* node in order to create small bumps:

[image]